# How to Count Values Between Ages in mvc5 using code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

**I want to collect values between ages like this table and I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 code-first - how can I display count values between the ages?**

[like this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgmxq.png)

****The ages I entered by a textbox how can I sort and collect them?**
What I have to do to count values like this in the view table? just between ages
entityframework?

Comment: Questions need to include the code **in the question itself**.

Comment: There is no such thing as *ASP.net MVC code-first*.  Code-First is an [tag:entity-framework] term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Count()

```
db.ages.count(x => x.age >= 5 & x.age <= 10)
```

this will give a a count between age 5 to 10 which is 5

also you can use user posted parameters to count ages

Comment: look it this mamoon https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53652726/data-collection-between-ages-in-mvc5