# Data collection between ages in mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have tried to collect data between ages but there is an error I do not know why here is my code my controller

```
 public ActionResult AllCuont()
    {
        var query = (from t in db.Pations
                     let range = (
                                  t.Age >= 0 && t.Age < 10 ? "0-9" :
                                  t.Age >= 11 && t.Age < 15 ? "10-14" :
                                  t.Age >= 15 && t.Age < 50 ? "15-50" :
                                  "50+"
                                  )
                     group t by range into g
                     select new UserRange { AgeRange = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }).ToList();
        //add the sum column.
        query.Add(new UserRange() { AgeRange = "Sum", Count = query.Sum(c => c.Count) });

        ViewBag.UserData = query;
        return View();
    }
```

**This is my model for To collect value**

```
  namespace Archive.Models
{
    public class UserRange
    {
        public string AgeRange { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Pation> Count { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**This is my view**

```
<table border="1">

<tr>
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.UserData)
    {
        <th>@item.AgeRange </th>
    }

</tr>
<tr>
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.UserData)
    {
        <td>@item.Count </td>
    }
</tr>
```

The problem in my controller here [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUduG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jmal hassn

> public IEnumerable Count { get; set; }

But you are passing Count which is an int by itself

> select new UserRange { AgeRange = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }

You have to pass a list of pations and than you count on that

Comment: yea bro Thank you, my friend. It  worked. Thank you very much, brother. I appreciate you standing with me brother i really thank you mamoon

Comment: @jmalhassn you are welcome dear, stack-overflow is our community like a family.. happy coding bro

Comment: hi   Mamoon Rasheed  how you doing  i have small question if i wont to display this data but by month i meas group  this ages but by month

Comment: @jmalhassn i doing great, thanks for asking, as you doing this by years now convert it months there wont be a problem, with these above you are a range from the years you have given so its quite flexible to any number given just convert with your perspectives. Hope this helps, if not than post a question or image like before will find a way of doing it right to your considerations

Comment: hi  Mamoon Rasheed  check this out it's like this question but i add something

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53756697/group-by-inside-group-by-using-entityframwork-in-mvc5